# SQL DELETE - Maximum number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, sql-delete

What limit should be placed on the number of rows to delete in a SQL statement?

We need to delete from 1 to several hundred thousand rows and need to apply some sort of best practise limit in order to not absolutely kill the SQL server or fill up the logs every time we empty a waste-basket.

This question is not specific to any type of database.

Comment: Such vague question cannot be answered. There is no silver bullet

Comment: We use batch nightly move job to move records from one table to another. We run batches of 10,000 and the performance hit is negligible.

Comment: You will need to try and add some limits and monitor server performance to get a best answer.

Comment: If you need to "empty a waste basket", why not use `truncate` instead of `delete`?

Comment: @AleksG: Often, a date-range of a waste-basket needs deletion. Or the waste-basket is not an independent table after all and has constraints which prevent using `truncate`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's a very very broad question that basically boils down to "it depends".  The factors that influence it include:

- What is your level of concurrency?  A delete statement places an exclusive lock on affected rows.  Depending on the databse engine, deleted data distribution, etc., that could escalate to page or entire table.  Can your data readers afford to be blocked for the duration of the delete?
- How complex is the delete statement?  How many other tables are you joining to, or are there complex WHERE clauses?  Sometimes the identification of rows to delete can be more "expensive" than the delete itself, so one big delete may be "cheaper".
- Are you fearful about deadlocks?  As you decrease the size of your delete, your deadlock "foot print" is reduced.  Ideally, single-row deletes will always succeed.
- Do you care about throughput performance?  As with any SQL statement, there is a generally constant amount of overhead (connection stuff, query parsing, returning results, etc.).  From a single-connection point of view, a 1000-line delete will be faster than 1000 x 1-line deletes.
- Don't forget about index maintenance overhead, fragmentation cleanup, or any triggers.  They can also affect your system.

In general, though, I benchmark at 1000-lines per statement.  Most systems I've worked with (sub-"enterprise") end up with a sweet-spot between 500 and 5000 records per delete.  I like to do something like this:

```
set rowcount 500

select 1    -- Just to force @@rowcount > 0
while @@ROWCOUNT > 0
delete from [table]
     [where ...]
```

Comment: +1, would add that if you're deleting a certain number of rows it's sometimes better to work up to it; so delete 10 then 100 then 1,000 as the DB has cached some of the work, which kind'a fits in with your point 4.

Comment: You generally have a LOT more supporting code to do anything but a "dummy" ramp up.  I also found that attempting to hit a "maximum" rows/second delete is pretty futile.  A better approach is to find an acceptable window (say 15 seconds), and attempt to delete as many rows at a time there.  In comment pseudo code:  pick 100 rows to delete.  Delete & get time info.  If time < 15 second, pick ROWS * 1.5 to delete; else pick rows * 0.5 to delete.  Repeat.  This will scale up your time-based throughput, and is sensitive to other activities on the DB.

Comment: For future readers, please see @SQLPhil 's answer below.  Based on the Microsoft Books Online, a future version of SQL Server will NOT honor `SET ROWCOUNT` for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements.  Best to use the `TOP` syntax instead.

Comment: It's best to put that sort of information at the top of the answer instead @jklemmack, with version numbers that your answer will work for and links to the answer that'll work for furture versions.

Answer (score 5):

Though limiting the number of rows affected by your delete using the set rowcount option and then performing a loop is very good (and I've used it many a time before), be aware that from SQL 2012 onwards this will not be an option (see [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx)).

Therefore, another option may be to limit the number of rows being deleted using the TOP clause.  i.e.

```
SELECT 1

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (#)
    FROM mytable
    [WHERE ...]
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a lot of triggers or integrity constraints to verify, deletion shouldn't be that expensive an operation.

But if you're that concerned about performance, my initial hunch would be to mark the appropriate rows as deleted and then physically delete them later during a periodic cleanup. But I'm not a big fan of this because you'll have to change any queries on that table to exclude logically- but not physically-deleted rows.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see a database that routinely deletes large amounts of rows in bulk, it makes me think the data model or processing design is not optimal. Why load 1 million rows and then delete them? If you need to do something like purge historical data, then consider table partitioning.

Comment: Russel. There might be reasons why you would load a million records; You  way want to perform calculations and store the calculated values before discarding the raw data.  But you do have a good point, proper design is important.

Answer (score 1):

I run into this question and found my own answer to be quite effective: do a subselect.

delete from urls where url in ( select top 10000 url from urls)

Answer (score 0):

a general answer is to drop the table and re-create it, that is a good performing solution, but applies for the full table

Comment: and what happens if there are procedures, functions, views etc dependent on the table you're dropping? You'll invalidate them for no good reason at all.