# What is the best way to delete billion of records in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 1 billion records in a table. I m trying to delete these records with two fields value. But it's taking too much time. So could you tell me any solution.

Comment: Are there any rows that you want to *keep* in this table?

Comment: If you don't care about these rows, use TRUNCATE. No undo logs will be stored. Or copy the required rows in a temp table, delete this table and rename temp.

Comment: Is this a real question? Also, why is it tagged mysql, oracle?

Comment: No i don't want to empty my table. i just want to delete some billion records with some fields value but it's taking too much time

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete all billion records, just truncate it. If you want some of the record exist you can use query `DELETE FROM ...`

Comment: ya i am trying to delete some records with some fields value. so it's taking too much time.

Answer (score 0):

If it's all you can use TRUNCATE
else copy what's you want to keep in tempory table, truncate and re-insert from temporary table

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ROWCOUNT 500
```

To delete 500 at a time

```
select 1    -- Just to force @@rowcount > 0
while @@ROWCOUNT > 0
delete from [table]
[where ...]
```

[link to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673349/sql-delete-maximum-number-of-rows)